# Is it possible to combine two private DNS zones into one policy definition

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I'm trying to deploy/register private DNS zones for private endpoint in app service > DNS configuration using custom policy but I'm not able to combine these two private DNS zones privatelink.api.azureml.ms and privatelink.notebooks.azure.net into one policy definition. Is this possible to combine these into one policy definition?

Looking forward for your help and advice on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Try this custom policy definition:

```
"parameters": {
  "privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceApi": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceApi",
      "description": null,
      "strongType": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones"
    }
  },
  "privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceNotebooks": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceNotebooks",
      "description": null,
      "strongType": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones"
    }
  }
},
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints"
      },
      {
        "count": {
          "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].groupIds[*]",
          "where": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateLinkServiceConnections[*].groupIds[*]",
            "equals": "amlworkspace"
          }
        },
        "greaterOrEquals": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
    "details": {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups",
      "roleDefinitionIds": [
        "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/4d97b98b-1d4f-4787-a291-c67834d212e7"
      ],
      "existenceCondition": {
        "count": {
          "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups/privateDnsZoneConfigs[*]",
          "where": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups/privateDnsZoneConfigs[*].privateDnsZoneId",
                "equals": "[parameters('privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceApi')]"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups/privateDnsZoneConfigs[*].privateDnsZoneId",
                "equals": "[parameters('privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceNotebooks')]"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "equals": 2
      },
      "deployment": {
        "properties": {
          "mode": "incremental",
          "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "parameters": {
              "privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceApi": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceNotebooks": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "privateEndpointName": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "location": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "resources": [
              {
                "name": "[concat(parameters('privateEndpointName'), '/deployedByPolicy')]",
                "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups",
                "apiVersion": "2020-07-01",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "properties": {
                  "privateDnsZoneConfigs": [
                    {
                      "name": "privatelink-api-azureml-ms",
                      "properties": {
                        "privateDnsZoneId": "[parameters('privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceApi')]"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "privatelink-notebooks-azure-net",
                      "properties": {
                        "privateDnsZoneId": "[parameters('privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceNotebooks')]"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "parameters": {
            "privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceApi": {
              "value": "[parameters('privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceApi')]"
            },
            "privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceNotebooks": {
              "value": "[parameters('privateDnsZoneIdAmlworkspaceNotebooks')]"
            },
            "privateEndpointName": {
              "value": "[field('name')]"
            },
            "location": {
              "value": "[field('location')]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```